# How to split stdout and stderr of shell command output cleanly and show the latter in Vim status line?

Tags: vim, statusbar, stderr

I use Vim as my dash board and monitor/update many tables with various external(filtering) commands, run from macros. They work terrifically, except the error output (not yet perfect, though I've resolved 80% of this message integration. See p.s. for the story for such application).

For example, the following table is for "I love coffee" game:

```
TYPE  | STAT |    NAME    | GOAL | DONE | TODO | S1 | S2 | S3
drink | .    | Latte      |  250 |  178 |   72 | .  | .  | .
drink | .    | Cocoa      |   99 |   46 |   50 | .  | 3  | .
drink | .    | Mocha      |  250 |  190 |   40 | 12 | 8  | .
drink | .    | Espresso   |   30 |    0 |   20 | 10 | .  | .
drink | .    | Iced Latte |   54 |    8 |   37 | .  | .  | 9
cake  | .    | Egg Tart   |   25 |   15 |    4 | 6  | .  | .
cake  | .    | Tiramisu   |   36 |    6 |   20 | 4  | 6  | .
cake  | .    | Brûlée     |   11 |    0 |    9 | .  | 2  | .
cake  | v    | Pudding    |   20 |   20 |    0 | .  | .  | .
```

I have the following macro in register s:

```
'oV}!order-update.pl 2>/tmp/vim.err ^M:if getfsize('/tmp/vim.err')>0|echo join(readfile('/tmp/vim.err'),"\|")|endif ^M'o
```

(`^M` is the character `ctrl-M`),
which helps update the `DONE` and `TODO` columns when I've touched the quantity in Store1/2/3. (And if finished, will make a `v` check and move the line down to the top of historical area.)

When there is something wrong in the numbers of `S1`/`S2`/`S3`, the redirection `2>` will spilt the stderr output from stdout output and save in `vim.err` file. (not to mess up the table)

The `if...endif` block will get the error output back and echo it to status line. It will print `Store3 drink: 9 > 8 max` when I put `9` in `S3`. (But `S3` can hold a maximum of 8 drinks.)

My problem is that the last ex command line:

```
:if getfsize('/tmp/vim.err')>0|echo join(readfile('/tmp/vim.err'),"\|")|endif
```

will be left in the status line if no error occur.

How can I improve it?

---

p.s.

### Story of such an application

The above (simplified) example demonstrates how I use Vim as a quick spreadsheet, for many tables I update every day. The benefit is - I don't have to leave my favorite Vim.

With some syntax highlighting, Vim can present those tables in the way best preferable to my eyes. (depending on those values)

With related filters, every table can be correctly updated according to the values' dependency.

I've developed many syntax/filter pairs for various projects over the years. And recently I got aware that I've not yet integrate the filter's error messages into Vim's environment. Such messages will be randomly merged into the normal output and make a messed-up table. (with Vim's default setting shellredir=">%s 2>$1")

My intention is to collect filter's stderr messages and fit them in Vim's status line.

Some results have been achieved in my experiments:

1. The "2>vim.err" specified in macro can overrule the default "2>&1" and split the stderr into the tempfile.
2. The readfile() function is great to read in the whole file.
3. The filter had better not exit with non-zero value for minor errors detected. Such value will make Vim do more things and raise a "Hit-enter" prompt.

And fitting the stderr messages smoothly in status line is my last piece of puzzle.

Comment: According to the suggestion of @IngoKarkat, this fix:
`:if getfsize('/tmp/vim.err')>0|echo join(readfile('/tmp/vim.err'),"\|")|else|echo|endif` will cleanly clear the code itself. A simple and perfect solution!
(And thanks @romainl to put my code in the block with scrollbar. I didn't successfully try it out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the "else|echo" is good solution to clear the status line all the time. It's ugly and not optimized for your macro.

Look at the content of your tmpfile vim.err, from stderr of your filter program. It should contains nothing if the filter doesn't see anything strange. Its empty content will help you clear the status line in the OK condition. I would rewrite your macro as (much simpler and cleaner):

```
'oV}!order-update.pl 2>/tmp/vim.err ^M:echo join(readfile('/tmp/vim.err'),"\|") ^M'o
```

In addtion, I don't agree to Mr. Karkat's comment: "Macro kept in a register is only good for a single editing session". In fact, macros are kept in .viminfo and available from session to session. They will never disappear unless you assign empty to them. In my mind, macro is as powerful as mapping. And further, macro is more convenient (easier to create and maintain) than mapping. At least you can save the escaping nightmare of mapping. I would transcribe a macro to a mapping only when it's mature enough and globally useful.

Comment: Thanks for your improvement! I prefer it. It's truly much cleaner.

Between macro and mapping, my way is similar to yours. I don't define mappings as often as record and refine a macro. I guess macros help 80% of my editing job.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping a macro in a register is fine for repetitive tasks done inside a single editing session. For things you need more often, I would define a proper *mapping*. With Vim, the "upgrade" is simple: The macro contents become the right-hand side of a `:map` command (with `|` becoming `<Bar>` and `^M` becoming `<CR>`), which you put into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>s 'oV}!order-update.pl ...
```

If you use `:nnoremap <silent>`, the keys will not be printed, and you should only see the result of `:echo`.

---

To pragmatically fix your macro, just add an `else|echo|endif` to the end.

Comment: Thank you.  Is "map-silent" the only rescue to make it quiet? (I've exhausted almost all the key combinations over the years. And I found macro is something similar but is easy to "overload" for different contexts/projects. It's why I prefer macro to mapping for this case. But if there is no rescue for macro, I may try to squeeze out some function keys for this purpose.)

Comment: You can also try the "else echo" for your macro, or append `| redraw` if that alone isn't enough.

Comment: I don't understand how you run out of mappings; you can have multiple keys on the left-hand side. So (some) mappings will get longer. Another alternative is a custom command; these usually are even longer, but you have command completion and no timeout on them.

Comment: Thanks for your reminding. I didn't catch the point of the "else|echo" fix for the macro, but it does the trick! After a short nap and seeing your words, I tried to insert the "else|echo" part and found it works like a charm! It clears itself perfectly and as simple as I expect. Thank you both!

Comment: For my understanding, such redundant "else|echo" part is an idiom of Vim for clearing the code left in status line. (quite special usage)

Comment: I wouldn't call it idiom, as I tried to convince you to use a mapping instead, and there `<silent>` would indeed be an idiom. This is just a workaround because you insist on using a macro, which hasn't any other form of silencing.

Comment: Thank you one more time. In fact, I was convinced, and have spent some hours reviewing Vim's documents for extensive knowledge and possibility about mapping. I've been using <silent> in my mappings since long ago. I post here just to know if macro has its own chance. (For your "run out of mapping" question, I replied late. I've fully made use of all the <F1>-<F12> and their friends with shift/control/alt. It's also true for <leader>[a-z]. alt-[a-z] usually conflicts with gui but I may get some back. I'm considering using <leader>x[a-z] for more mapping need. However, I still need macros.)